# SQL where exists not filtering correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Hi I am doing a data driven subscription for an SSRS report and just want to email users where the reports actually have data. I researched it and found out I need an EXISTS clause. However some how my statement pulls back data where there should not be any data.

```
select Companyid,Email 
from [VW_ADMIN] 
where EXISTS(SELECT  
    [RESOURCEID]
    ,[COMPANYNAME]
    ,[COMPANYID]
    ,[QUALIFIED]
    ,[FIRSTNAME]
    ,[MI]
    ,[LASTNAME]
    ,[SUFFIX]
    ,[TYPE]
    ,[LOCATION]
    ,[LICENSENUM]
    ,[QUALIFICATIONID]
    ,[EXPIRATIONDATE]    
    ,[DATE]
    ,[AFBDATE]
    ,[AFADATE]
  FROM [VW_OVERVIEW2]
  where 
    ([COMPANYID]=4)
    and 
    ((EXPIRATIONDATE between (Select convert (Varchar(10),(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)),101)) and (select convert( Varchar(10),(select eomonth(getdate())),101)))
    or ([EXPIRATIONDATE] < (Select convert (Varchar(10),(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)),101)))
    or ([AFCDATE] between (Select convert (Varchar(10),(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)),101)) and (select convert( Varchar(10),(select eomonth(getdate())),101)))
    or ([AFCDATE] < (Select convert (Varchar(10),(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)),101)))
    or ([AFBDATE] between (Select convert (Varchar(10),(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)),101)) and (select convert( Varchar(10),(select eomonth(getdate())),101)))
    or ([AFBDATE] < (Select convert (Varchar(10),(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)),101)))
    or ([AFADATE] between (Select convert (Varchar(10),(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)),101)) and (select convert( Varchar(10),(select eomonth(getdate())),101)))
    or ([AFADATE] < (Select convert (Varchar(10),(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)),101)))
    ))
and active=1 
and CATEGORYID=1 
and roleid=3
```

When I test my report query(query below) no records return for companyid=4 But for the query above it returns records. Basically I insert the below report query into the where clause above

```
declare @companyid int,@begdate datetime,@enddate datetime;
set @companyid = 4
set @begdate = (Select convert (Varchar(10),(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)),101))
set @enddate = (select convert( Varchar(10),(select eomonth(getdate())),101))
SELECT  
    [RESOURCEID]
    ,[COMPANYNAME]
    ,[COMPANYID]
    ,[QUALIFIED]
    ,[FIRSTNAME]
    ,[MI]
    ,[LASTNAME]
    ,[SUFFIX]
    ,[TYPE]
    ,[LOCATION]
    ,[LICENSENUM]
    ,[QUALIFICATIONID]
    ,[EXPIRATIONDATE]    
    ,[AFCDATE]
    ,[AFBDATE]
    ,[AFADATE]
  FROM [VW_OVERVIEW2]
  where 
    ([COMPANYID]=@COMPANYID)
    and 
    ((EXPIRATIONDATE between @BEGDATE and @ENDDATE)
    or ([EXPIRATIONDATE] < @BEGDATE)
    or ([AFCDATE] between @BEGDATE and @ENDDATE)
    or ([AFCDATE] < @BEGDATE)
    or ([AFBDATE] between @BEGDATE and @ENDDATE)
    or ([AFBDATE] < @BEGDATE)
    or ([AFADATE] between @BEGDATE and @ENDDATE)
    or ([AFADATE] < @BEGDATE)
    )
```

Comment: What data type is `[AFCDATE]`? My first thought is that you might have a datatype mismatch. Your first query compares `[AFCDATE]` (and similar columns) against strings, whereas the second query compares against `datetime`s. If `[AFCDATE]` is a string, it may be in a format that doesn't natively convert correctly to the `datetime` you have in your variables.

Comment: @Xedni all the dates are nvarchar That is why I am converting the Getdate() to compare.

Comment: Can you give me an example of what the string date looks like? As I said, your second query, despite the fact that you're telling it to convert it to a `varchar(10)`, is ultimately NOT going into a `varchar(10)` variable, but rather a `datetime` variable (mostly rendering the `convert` logic redundant)

Comment: @Xedni You are right! I changed the bottom query `@begdate` and `@enddate` to nvarchar(10) and now it returns data.  my dates look like this 04/27/2018. Not sure what is the best way to format this now so it filters correctly.Like I said the report runs fine I did this mostly for testing purposes.

Comment: @Xedni I think I have figured it out.  I removed the convert function from the top query and it looks to be filtering correctly. THANK YOU for noticing that. I have no idea how you caught that but this is definitely a learning experience for me now.

Comment: You really need to store dates as date or datetime. Storing them as varchar is a nightmare. Your date checks are also quite redundant. Why check if a date is between now and the end of the current month OR the date is less than now. That is the same thing as single predicate checking for less than the end of the current month. As for the issue at hand it is guess work because we have no idea what the tables, data or desired output is.

Comment: @SeanLange I didn't design it this way, There must be a reason they did this but I do not know I just picked this up.  The report has conditional filtering so if the dates are before, they are expired and light up red and in between are warnings.

Comment: I understand about the tables but the conditional filtering doesn't mean you have to do bizarre where clauses. Change that logic so it makes sense. In your second query this is the exact same thing as your first two predicates. EXPIRATIONDATE <= @ENDDATE